# Pass checkbox values to other form element values on conditions

Tags: javascript, html

Simple markup, 2 tables full of checkboxes. Paypal form submit at the bottom

I have tried a few methods unsuccessfully. Maybe if someone could point me even in the right direction of how to go about doing what I need.

Needs:

1. Any checkbox that gets checked, add that checkboxes value text to the paypal `#item_name` value field. If it is unchecked, remove the value text from paypal `#item_name` field.
2. These are the quantities and pricing. That means any checkboxes anywhere in the chart. It only matters the amount that are checked - **not the order.** If 1 - 6 are checked the paypal `#amount` value is $4.00. If 7 - 12 are checked the value is $6.00. If 13 - 18 are checked the value is $8.00. If 19 - 23 are checked the value is $10.00
3. Only 23 checkboxes allowed to be checked at one time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>samples grid</title>
      
      <style>
      
        table, td, th {border: 1px solid black;}
      
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <table id="samples-a" title="samples grid">
      <thead>
        <tr>
       <th colspan="5">
         samples A
       </th>
     </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
     <th colspan="4">
       sub header
     </th>
     <th colspan="1">
       sub header
     </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
      </tr>  
      <tbody>
        <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample1">
      <label>sample1</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample2">
      <label>sample2</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample3">
      <label>sample3</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample4">
      <label>sample4</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample5">
      <label>sample5</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample6">
      <label>sample6</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample7">
      <label>sample7</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample8">
      <label>sample8</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample9">
      <label>sample9</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample10">
      <label>sample10</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample11">
      <label>sample11</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample12">
      <label>sample12</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample13">
      <label>sample13</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample14">
      <label>sample14</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample15">
      <label>sample15</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample16">
      <label>sample16</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample17">
      <label>sample17</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample18">
      <label>sample18</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample19">
      <label>sample19</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample20">
      <label>sample20</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample21">
      <label>sample21</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample22">
      <label>sample22</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample23">
      <label>sample23</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample24">
      <label>sample24</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample25">
      <label>sample25</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample26">
      <label>sample26</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample27">
      <label>sample27</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample28">
      <label>sample28</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample29">
      <label>sample29</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample30">
      <label>sample30</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample31">
      <label>sample31</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample32">
      <label>sample32</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample33">
      <label>sample33</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>  
    
    </table>
    
    <table id="samples-b">
      <thead>
        <tr>
       <th colspan="5">
         samples B
       </th>
     </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
     <th colspan="5">
       sub header
     </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
       sub header
     </th>
     <th colspan="1">
       sub header
     </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
        <th>sub header</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample34">
      <label>sample34</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample35">
      <label>sample35</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample36">
      <label>sample36</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample37">
      <label>sample37</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample38">
      <label>sample38</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample39">
      <label>sample39</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample40">
      <label>sample40</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample41">
      <label>sample41</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th colspan="5">
         sub header
       </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
          <th>sub header</th>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample42">
      <label>sample42</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample43">
      <label>sample43</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample44">
      <label>sample44</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample45">
      <label>sample45</label>
       </td>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample46">
      <label>sample46</label>
       </td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="checkbox" value="sample47">
      <label>sample47</label>
       </td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
      
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="elsa@wool-clothing.com">
          <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
          <input id="item_name" type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
          <input id="amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
          <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
          <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
          <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
          <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.wool-clothing.com/thanks.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.wool-clothing.com/cancel.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.wool-clothing.com/clothing/">
          <!--
       <input type="hidden" name="weight" value="0.37">
          <input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="lbs">
          <input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="4.00" />
       -->
          <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_SM.gif:NonHosted">
          <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>  
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've an answer for the first and the third points of your question:

```
var checkboxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).filter(function (input) {
    var type = input.getAttribute('type'),
        // && is needed to make sure that the attribute exists
        isCheckbox = type && type == 'checkbox';
    return isCheckbox;
}),
    itemName = document.getElementById('item_name'),
    amount = document.getElementById('amount'),
    maxCheckboxesSelectedThreshold = 23,
    // by default
    checkboxesSelected = 0;

checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // checked variable describes if current checkbox is checked RIGHT AFTER the click is performed, NOT before
        var checked = this.checked,
            value = this.value,
            checkboxNumber;
        this.checked = checked && (checkboxesSelected++ < maxCheckboxesSelectedThreshold) || (checkboxesSelected-- && false);
        console.log("checked amount: " + checkboxesSelected);
        if (this.checked) {
            itemName.value = value;
            checkboxNumber = parseInt(value.replace('sample', ''));
        } else {
            itemName.value = '';
        }

// based on amount of checked checkboxes, change the price value
    if (checkboxesSelected <=6) {
            amount.value = '4$';
        } else if (checkboxesSelected >=7 && checkboxesSelected <=12) {
            amount.value = '6$';
        } else if (checkboxesSelected >= 13 && checkboxesSelected <= 18) {
            amount.value = '8$';
        } else if (checkboxesSelected >= 19 && checkboxesSelected <= 23) {
            amount.value = '10$';
        }
    });

});
```

There's smth you should know to understand how the following code works:

```
this.checked = checked && (checkboxesSelected++ < maxCheckboxesSelectedThreshold) || (checkboxesSelected-- && false);
```

1. `A && B` logical operator is `true` if both of operands are `true`. It checkes first A, and if it's `false`, then it doesn't go to B because all the expression is evaluated as `false`; if A is `true`, the operator goes to B and checkes it too.
2. `A || B` operator is `true` if at least one of operands is `true`. JS checkes A first, and if it's `true`, it doesn't go to B, it returns `true` for all the expression `A || B`

Based on this, you know now that:

if `checked && (checkboxesSelected++ < maxCheckboxesSelectedThreshold)` is true, this means that the checkbox hasn't been checked previously and amount of already checked checkboxes is less than the threshold. So JS returns true, checkes the checkbox and increases the counter for the checkboxes selected. JS doesn't go to right hand side operand! (`(checkboxesSelected-- && false)`).

But if the first part is false, then JS goes to this part: `(checkboxesSelected-- && false)`. By this time the counter has been increased, and we need to decrease it back by doing this: `checkboxesSelected--`. `&& false` makes the expression always false, because if JS has reached this place, the checkbox mustn't be checked! So all the expression `checked && (checkboxesSelected++ < maxCheckboxesSelectedThreshold) || (checkboxesSelected-- && false);` is false, and `this.checked` becomes `false`. So the checkbox isn't checked after the click.

> > If 1 - 6 are checked the paypal #amount value is $4.00. If 7 - 12 are checked the value is $6.00. If 13 - 18 are checked the value is
> >     $8.00. If 19 - 23 are checked the value is $10.00
>
> You should clarify your request. What if 2,4 and 8, 10 are checked?
>   Should the field be cleared, for example?

The code posted previously has been updated after the request clarification.

Comment: wow. This is a lot to take in at the moment. Thank you very much for this I will test this out soon. For clarification of the third part, I meant any checkboxes in any order(1-6 anywhere on the chart, 7-12 anywhere on the chart etc.) They are all going to be the same price in quantities.

Comment: So do you mean just amount of checked checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, just the amount matters. Sorry sometimes I have a problem with wording things correctly. I have updated the original question as well to add this clarity.

Comment: I've updated the code according to your clarification

Comment: I have tried this and it partially works. It will only pass one checkbox value into the #item_name value at a time. Its always the latter checkbox anywhere on the chart that gets the value passed. So it doesn't matter how many I check on the grid, it's only passing the farthest down checkbox value.

Comment: I had to also add an initial value to #amount to get the script to partially work. And it will not update that value accordingly either

Comment: EDIT: Actually it appears that its simply the last checkbox thats manually checked anywhere gets added. The threshold count for the checkboxes works fine.

Comment: Sorry, but how to treat your words? "pass that value to the paypal #item_name value field". If you wrote "add that value", that is, if you clarified your request, the code would be different. Just passing the value was treated by me the way your words sounded to me. That's the question of establishing the requirements. I didn't know EXACTLY what you supposed by saying "pass the value to..."

Comment: "had to also add an initial value to #amount to get the script to partially work" - this works in general, I don't know how you're trying to integrate and adopt the script. My code doesn't access #amount value, it only assigns some values to this element. So whether you initialize its value or not, this doesn't play role in this restricted context (that is, until you provide some more details of what and how you're trying to do)

Comment: "EDIT: Actually it appears that its simply the last checkbox thats manually checked anywhere gets added. " - exactly. Than you can play around with it, for example, itemName.value +=  value; to just add selected value to the existing value of that field

Comment: I have edited the original question for better clarity now. Thanks for this. I will play around with it some now.